# Can I pass simple arrays in redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I started to learn better redux + reactjs

For example I have a news or list reducer that should return an array contain news items :

```js
const list = [
    {id: 1, title: 'One'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Two'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Three'}
]

export function newsReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_NEWS':
            return list
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This code works right, but in other articles I saw they passed parameters with [...state, ...] and immutable format ...

So can I pass parameters simple or I should pass in immutable format ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: Yes you can pass simple arrays in if that suits your needs best.

If you are going to use a simple array, then make sure to return a *new* array when making modifications.

For example:

```
export function listChangeReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch action.type {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      // don't do this because you're mutating your state
      // state.push(action.item);
      // instead do this
      state = state.slice();
      state.push(action.item);
      // or alternatively you can use the destruct syntax
      //[...state, action.item];
      return state;

    break;
  }
};
```

You aren't required to use immutablejs data structures with redux. It is just recommended so that you don't accidentally mutate your data structures.

The [documentation](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#why-is-immutability-required-by-redux) states that the data needs to be immutable because

> Both Redux and React-Redux employ shallow equality checking. In
>   particular:
>
> Redux's combineReducers utility shallowly checks for reference changes
>   caused by the reducers that it calls.